# Pandas pivot_table force column structure?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe I want to summarize and send in an email, is there any way to explicitly pass the columns IN THE ORDER I want them displayed?

```
df.pivot_table(index='Owner', values=['Matches', 'W', 'D', 'L', 'Pts'], aggfunc=sum)
```

returns this column order (index, sorted value columns a-z): Owner, D, L, Matches, Pts, W

Currently doing this in two-ish operations:

```
values_cols = ['Matches', 'W', 'D', 'L', 'Pts']
df2 = df.pivot_table(index='Owner', values=values_cols, aggfunc=sum)
df2 = df2.loc[:,values_cols]
```

Just curious if I am doing something wrong or is this expected behavior?

Tried sort=False, then checked the pivot_table documentation..

Comment: this is expected behavior,`pivot_table` returns sorted column values. you can chain them though: `df.pivot_table(index='Owner', values=values_cols, aggfunc=sum).loc[:,values_cols]` for a one liner. but nothing wrong with your approach IMO

Comment: Thanks for feedback @anky.. I'm going to use archer's answer below, but it's all the same in the end. I realize I could drop loc in the end, but was hoping there was a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with pivot_table adding reindex at the end:

```
result = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Owner', values=values_cols, aggfunc=sum).reindex(columns=values_cols)
```

Comment: thanks for this answer.. I'd say this is more pythonic and will migrate to it.

Comment: Great. Please accept the answer if it's ok and there is no other better suggestion. Cheers